# Fetch records of parent table depending on count of children

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `A` and `B`, where `B` has foreign keys to `A` (i.e. `A` can have zero or many children in `B` whereas each `B` record exactly belongs to one `A` record).

Now I want to fetch all records from `A` where **the number of children** in `B` is lower than *x* (including *zero*).

How can I achieve this comparison of the aggregate function?

```sql
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B.id) AS child_cnt
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B
         ON A.id = B.foreign_id
GROUP BY A.id
```

However, I cannot add a `WHERE` condition for `child_cnt` of course. Any pointers to how the desired result can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use having for filter the result

```
SELECT A.*, ifnull(COUNT(B.id), 0) AS child_cnt
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.foreign_id
GROUP BY A.id
HAVING COUNT(B.id) < X
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `HAVING` such as

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B.id) AS child_cnt
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B
         ON A.id = B.foreign_id
GROUP BY A.id
HAVING child_cnt < 17;
```